# Unable to set /mnt/* as user-dirs.dirs

Tags: ubuntu, xdg-user-dirs

I would like to set the root of some of my mounts as the user-dirs, however when using the root it returns nothing.

Setting root mount

```
$ xdg-user-dirs-update --set VIDEOS /mnt/videos/

$ cat /home/hutber/.config/user-dirs.dirs | grep XDG_VIDEOS_DIR
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/mnt/videos/"
```

Trying to view files in videos:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ ll /home/hutber/Videos/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 hutber hutber 4096 May 11 15:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 34 hutber hutber 4096 Jun  1 11:45 ../
```

Comment: That is NOT how this works. "/home/hutber/Videos/"  what does that directory have to do with it when you set it to "/mnt/videos/"? `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/mnt/videos/"` is not a symlink.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rinzwind. Forgive me, but what use is `user-dirs.dirs` if its not to point folders to other folders in the system what is `user-dirs.dirs` for?

Comment: It is to point the desktop components to where your default directories are.  Nautilus, Nemo, downloads from browsers. It is part of the desktop setup. Not part of the "server"  setup.